# How many rewrite rules can we add to web.config in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, kentico-12

I am using a file called on the web. config's rewrite rule section to add rewrite rules. I have 3000 rules to be added to this file, but my website is not working if I add more than 1000. How many rewrite rules can I add to my file?

Comment: https://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh-TW/502ce133-ec84-460d-873b-86b879e9ae84/maximum-number-of-rewrite-rules?forum=iisurlrewritemodule

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a rewrite map rule in the web config file as below

```
<rules>
<rule name="Rewrite Rule">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{StaticRewrites:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" />
</rule>
```

You can follow the link step it'll help you to rewrite the map from the rewrite rule
[Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module)